# Selection Sort algorithm in C doesn't print the entire sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int smallest(int [],int);
int select_sort(int[],int);

int smallest(int arr[],int len){
        int small_index=0;
        int small=arr[0];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                if(arr[i]<small){small=arr[i];
                                 small_index=i;
                                                }
                            }
        return small_index;
}
int select_sort(int arra[],int len){
    int new_arra[100];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            int small=smallest(arra,len);
            new_arra[i]=arra[small];
            printf("%d",new_arra[i]);
    }

    return new_arra;

}
int main()
{
    int arr[100]={6,1,0,-2,18};
    select_sort(arr,5);
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code for the selection sorting program and i know ideally i should be using the dynamic allocation for arrays in the select_sort function, but i was attempting it without it. It is supposed to print the array in an ascending order and I think I am messing up variable assignment somewhere, because when i run the program it **only prints the smallest integer of the input array len number of times and not the rest of them.**

Comment: That's because your function `smallest` will always return the same smallest element of the array. You have to somehow mark or remove the elements you already handled, such that they will be ignored in all future actions.

Comment: Typically, selection sort works in place, ie you switch the smallest element of the remaining unsorted array with the current position. Then you advance one index and skip the already sorted elements in the search

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind messing up with your initial array, you can do:

```
     int select_sort(int arra[],int len)
        {
            int maxValue = Integer.Max_Value; 
            int new_arra[100];
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                int small=smallest(arra,len);
                new_arra[i]=arra[small];
                arra[small]= maxValue;
                printf("%d",new_arra[i]);
        }
    
        return new_arra;
```

bear in mind that this is highly unefficient